# Get min from parts of the row that the position of the row corresponds to a cell in another row

Tags: excel

I am new in excel and I want to have Min from a certain cell G1613: untill a cell in the same row(G) with the position that I wrote in another row like(G1617) in the case that 1617 was written in the row M1.I really stuck in it.could you please help me to solve it.or also how can I have Min(G1613:G1617) in this form: Min(G1613:G(1613+4)) which 4 written in possition M1?

Comment: like `=MIN(G1613:INDEX(G1613:G10000,M1))` as non-volatile function?

Comment: actually i tried it like this but it gives me REF!=MIN(Einfügen!G1613:INDEX(Einfügen!1613:3213;M63))

Comment: it should be: `=MIN(Einfügen!G1613:INDEX(Einfügen!G1613:G3213;M63))`... do not miss the G

Comment: actually i tried it like this but it gives me REF!, =MIN(Einfügen!G1613:INDEX(Einfügen!1613:3213;M63)) and actually I have a frequency domain between 1-3000 MHz and I had diffrent pairs, I would like excel to calculate automatically the minimum of each pair in diffrent frequency domain, eg: from 1-4 or 1-20 MHz, I have diffrent variety of frequencies,

Comment: I mean I can have 100 frequencies between 1-4 for one case and only 2 for the other case so the possition of my data changed all the time, so I used countif to know how many frequencies I have eg between 1-4 and then sum this number to 1613(which my frequencies start from this possition). now I want excel to take the min of my data but I have to write something like =MIN(Einfügen!G1613:INDEX(Einfügen!1613:3213;M63)) which M row located in another worksheet(NEXT)

Comment: the problem is that inside the `INDEX`, you just use `1613:3213` which should be `G1613:G3213`... and if M63 is at scheet `NEXT` then simply change the `M63` to `NEXT!M63`

Comment: thanks, I did it, but it still gives me #REF!

Comment: please run the formula via "evaluate formula" to get the step which returns the #REF... ive tested it several times and it worked without any problem... please check that M63 is not bigger that the range itself... if it is 1 then just  `Einfügen!G1613` is used. If it is 2 then `Einfügen!G1613:G1614` is used and so on... and at 1601 it will use the whole range while 1602 will return #REF... please doublecheck that

Comment: tnx, but I think zou miss understood, I want to have =MIN(Einfügen!G1613:G1617) but instead of writing all the time for diffrent frequencies different equation I want to write it like =MIN(Einfügen!G1613:G1613+4) in the case that 4 was written in Next(M62)

Comment: as It is,`=MIN(Einfügen!G1613:INDEX(Einfügen!G1613:G3213;NEXT!M63))` would go for min(G1613:G1614) if m63 is 2 and min(G1613:G1616) if m63 is 4

Comment: TNX MAN IT WORKS!!, I did the same always but in M63 I wrote 1617 instead of 4, BTW thanks a milion times:)